# Access to html basic protected image via SapUI5 & Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication, sapui5

I'm trying to access an image protected by a simple http basic authentication mechanism. This example works fine when using my browser

```
...
var mImage = sap.m.Image("Im1");
mImage.setSrc("http://user:password@192.168.0.100/image.jpg");
...
var page = new sap.m.Page({
title: "Image",
content: mImage        
}
```

Yet when I wrap it in a Cordova container (Android) this simple way of attaching user+pw does not seem to work. The webserver responds with a 401 error and my app does not send an authentication header.

The next step I've tried was to send a XmlHttRequest before trying to access time image URL:

```
        var xhr =new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://192.168.0.100/image.jpg", true, "user", "password");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                alert(xhr.responseText); //returns the image in text form i.e. authentication works fine
                mImage.setSrc("http://192.168.0.100/image.jpg") //returns a 401
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
```

Yet another failure. I was under the impression that once I am authenticated I will get a session. But apparently the xhr session and the sap.m.image session seem to be apart.

Any thoughts on how to tackle this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this appears to be a bug in the Android Webview. It is fixed in Android 5- This is fine for me and my example above works fine